# Visual Studio 2017 v15.3 doesn't copy nlog.config

Tags: visual-studio-2017, nlog

I just updated to `Visual Studio 2017 v15.3` and `Core 2.0 SDK`.

I'm working with Igans Sakalauskas' `Net Core Knockout project`, it was built with `Core 1.1` in VS 2017.

https://ignas.me/tech/net-core-knockoutjs-web-application/

I've left `EnableDefaultContentItems`to the default of true and removed the `Content Include` statements from the `.csproj` file in the `WebApplication1.Web` project.

He is using `nlog` and there is a `nlog.config` in the root of the project. The project builds successfully but throws a `file not found error` when ran.  It is looking for the `nlog.config` in the `WebApplication1.Web\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1` folder.  If I manually copy the file the project runs and all the tests pass.

What I cannot get to work is for VS to copy the `nlog.config` when the project builds.

If I add

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="nlog.*" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

to the `.csproj` I get the `Duplicate 'Content' items ... The duplicate items were: 'nlog.config'` error.  https://aka.ms/sdkimplicititems

If I comment out the `Contnet Include` and set the `EnableDefaultContentItems` to false

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <EnableDefaultCompileItems>false</EnableDefaultCompileItems>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I get a
`Suppression State Error    CS5001  Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point`

If I then restore the `Content Inculde' statements it gives this error:

`Duplicate 'Content' items ... The duplicate items were: 'list of files'` error

The `Default Content Items` is working with `.js` and `.cs` files in the `wwwroot` sub-folders.

If VS throws the `Duplicate Content` error when I `Content Include` an item why does it not copy the file without the `Content Include`?

In VS 2017 15.3 how do you configure the copying of a file `nlog.config` from the project's root to a bin sub-directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is nothing to do with duplicate content items.

Revert to the [recommended approach to handling duplicate content errors](https://www.danielcrabtree.com/blog/273/fixing-the-duplicate-content-error-after-upgrading-visual-studio-2017) in Visual Studio 2017; this is what you started with:

> I've left EnableDefaultContentItems to the default of true and removed
>   the Content Include statements from the .csproj file in the
>   WebApplication1.Web project.

Now add this to your .csproj file:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Update="nlog.config">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

This tells Visual Studio to update the existing content rule (the automatically generated one) to make it copy the file into the output directory on build.

Comment: Hello Daniel. I was just about to post my answer which was to highlight in VS `nlog.config` and change the `Copy to Output Directory` status in Properties which writes your answer to the `.csproj`.  But you beat me to it so you get the Vote.  Still doesn't answer the secondary question of why setting `EnableDefaultContentItems` to false is not working.  Do you have any idea on that?  Please let me know so I'll know to post a separate question if you don't know.

Comment: @Joe The most likely issues are: `EnableDefaultCompileItems` is not in the right location and not being applied or there is an issue with the content includes. It is easiest to just avoid the whole issue by removing the content includes and removing `EnableDefaultCompileItems`, this has worked well for me and I haven't found any need for `EnableDefaultCompileItems`.